# update current database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I'm making a WordPress plugin and I need to update tables for the current database in a query. However, instead of writing the database name into the sql, I need some way to select it in the query so that way it will work no matter what your database's name is. This is the code I currently have:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `wp_plugin_development` . `wp_users` SET `user_pass` = ? WHERE `user_login` = ?") or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user_password[$i], $user_login[$i]);
```

`wp_plugin_development` is my current database name, but needs to be replaced with some other way of selecting the database name. I wish I could write something like `UPDATE SELECT DATABASE()` but that obviously doesn't work. Maybe there's an entirely different way to code this? I still consider myself new to all this, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The database name would already be specified in the wp-config.php file right?  If you are connected to the database, you can just run statements to manipulate the tables.  The name of the database doesn't matter at this point. UPDATE wp_users... should work

Comment: @claydwg I should probably explain this a little more. What this code is doing is taking the hashed passwords from one database (defined in `$conn`) and copying them to the current database (`wp_plugin_development`). So what happens when I remove the database name from this query is it creates new passwords for the users, which is what I don't want. That's why I need to include some way of getting the current database name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the *current* database name, because the connection is already established with the current database.
You need the tablename! The prefix is set when setting up wordpress. You **need** the prefix, because every installation is different.

The proper Wordpress way is like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'plugin_development';
```

The prefix is stored (`wp_`). In WP; you don't use PDO or MySqli directly, you work with the global `$wpdb` object.

```
$wpdb->update($table_name, $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null);
```

If you really need the database name, it's stored in `$wpdb->dbname;`.
Here are examples and the class reference:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: I use WordPress's framework where I see it is convenient, but for some cases I don't see any solutions. Or sometimes I use a bit of both in the same loop or conditional. For example, in the code I posted I'm taking all the users' hashed passwords from one database and applying them to the current database (that already has the same users). In order to do this with the WordPress framework, I have to turn off password hashing in one of the config files (or it would "rehash" them), and that's a big security risk. So I choose to use a mysqli query for this instead.

Comment: Your answer did help me think about my approach differently though. `$conn` was the connection to the other database. So I made a new connection to the current database called `$this_db` using `$wpdb` and changed the `$stmt` connection to use `$this_db` instead.

It works just like I wanted it to this way.

Answer (score 0):

I was using another database as the connection method (this was defined in the `$conn` variable). So I made a new connection to the current database using `$wpdb` and named it `$this_db`. Now I don't have to specify the database name in the query and it works like I want it to. For better context, here's the code I added/changed:

```
$thisServername = $wpdb->dbhost;
$thisUsername = $wpdb->dbuser;
$thisPassword = $wpdb->dbpassword;
$thisDBname = $wpdb->dbname;

$this_db = new mysqli($thisServername, $thisUsername, $thisPassword, $thisDBname);

$stmt = $this_db->prepare("UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_pass` = ? WHERE `user_login` = ?") or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user_password[$i], $user_login[$i]);
```

So, for solving this specific issue, this solution works. Sorry I forgot to mention using the external database. That was an important thing I left out of the question. And thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score -1):

The function `database()` returns the DB name - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database   - 
so you can run `SELECT DATABASE();` first to get the DB name.

Comment: I gotta be honest, I have no clue how I would write that in order for it to work with the `$stmt` thing I got going on.

Comment: Wordpress coding is strictly against using native stuff. There are even mechanism to block your plugin/theme if it doesn't fit the WP guidelines.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I focused on the MySQL part of the question and didn't know the WP restriction.